# I want to load a specific class based on a flag instead of loading two class and using one the required in Springs

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, marker-interfaces

In configurations I have a flag isFlagEnabled.

So I have to read the flag from spring config and based on that I want to execute specific class A or B . Meaning I want to load A class only when isFlagEnabled is true and similarly load class B only when isFlagEnabled is false.

I have written the below code but i am stuck when ingesting .

```
public interface MediatorInt {

public void init();

}

class A implements MediatorInt {
        init() { It does some task }
    }

class B implements MediatorInt {
    init(){ It does some task }
}

public class MasterNewGenImpl {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("config")
    private Configuration config;

    @Autowired
    MediatorInt mediatorInt;

    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass());

    public void startService() {
        mediatorInt.init();
    }
}
```

context.xml file

```
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.ca"/>
    <bean id="config" class="com.ca.configuration.ConfigImplementation"/>    
    <bean id="masterSlave" class="com.ca.masterslave.A"/>
    <bean id="systemState" class="com.ca.masterslave.B"/>
    <bean id="masterSlaveNewGen" class="com.ca.masterslave.MasterNewGenImpl">
    <property name = "mediatorOrMasteSlave" value="#{config.getMediatorMode() == 'true' ? 'systemState' : 'masterSlave'}" />
</bean>
```

So now i am not getting how to inject specific object based on the config flag . I want to make it through Lazy-init so that other object will not get loaded when its not required .
I greatly appreciate the suggestions.

Comment: which version of spring are you using

Comment: i am using Spring 4.1.6.RELEASE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are okay with spring scanning both the implementations, then you can select the needed one using `@Qualifier`. If you want spring not to scan some class based on a property, You can use [@Conditional](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Conditional.html)

```
class SomeCondition implements Condition {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {

        String isFlagEnabled = context.getEnvironment().getProperty("isFlagEnabled");
        return isFlagEnabled.equals("true"));
    }
}

@Configuration
@Conditional(value = SomeCondition.class)
class A implements MediatorInt {
        init() { It does some task }
 }
```

In the above config, class A is scanned only if `matches()` in `SomeCondition` class returns true, where you can define the condition.

Comment: Thanks for responding . Sorry here i am not clear about the the Condition Interface and how can i get the ConditionContext context in my method

Comment: You don't have to do anything, Spring will inject it for you. You can use the above code as it is, only thing is you should have isFlagEnabled in your properties file

Comment: Yes i have the flag in my properties . I copied the code as it is , it giving error for Condition ,ConditionText and for AnnotatedTypeMetadata its recommending me to import org.springframework.core.type.AnnotatedTypeMetadata; so can you please tell me which class i should import conditiontext

Comment: `import org.springframework.context.annotation.Condition;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionContext;
import org.springframework.core.type.AnnotatedTypeMetadata;`

Comment: My lead is suggesting me to Achieve this using SPEL so i have tried to load beans using SPEL as i ashown in the context.xml but my configurations itself not getting loaded am getting Exception as    "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParserConfiguration.<init>(Lorg/springframework/expression/spel/SpelCompilerMode;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)V"

Comment: add primary annotation along with Conditional annotation

`@Primary    
@Configuration    
@Conditional(value = SomeCondition.class)    
class A implements MediatorInt {    
        init() { It does some task }    
 }
`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier( "systemState" )
MediatorInt systemSateMeidator;

@Autowired
@Qualifier( "masterSlave" )
MediatorInt masterSateMeidator;
```

With `@Qualifier` you are instructing spring on how to fulfill your component request.