# Autowire reference beans into a property depending list by type

Tags: java, spring

i'm searching for this since a view hours, but can't find anything matching my problem directly:

In my application I want to have different beans (different working classes) stored in a list of an component. Later on I want to iterate through this list and call a execution method (same naming but different behaviour)

So far its not the Problem for me, I created the Interface IInterface and used the @Autowired Annotation to inject a list of all the beans which implements the Interface.

Interface:

```
public interface IInterface
{
    public void work();
}
```

Implementation1:

```
@Component("impl1")
public class Impl1 implements IInterface
{
    @Override
    public void work()
    {
        //do fancy stuff
    }
}
```

Implementation2:

```
@Component("impl2")
public class Impl2 implements IInterface
{
    @Override
    public void work()
    {
        //do other fancy stuff
    }
}
```

Scheduling class

```
@Component    
public class Scheduler
{
    @Autowired
    private List<IInterface> impls;

    @Scheduled(cron = "${scheduling.job.cron}")
    public void triggeredWork()
    {
        for (IInterface impl : impls)
        {
            impl.work();
        }
    }
}
```

Until this point i have no problem with the implementation, but the discribed setting only works for one environment, now I have to set up another environment with another implementation class (e.g. impl3) and without impl1.
One approach was to mix up annotation based config and xml config, for this I have to define a new Beans.xml for every environment and use it this way for e.g. environment1 (I'm not sure if this is right):

```
<bean id="scheduler" 
  class="com.example.Scheduler">
    <property name="impls" ref="implList">
</bean>

< bean id="implList" class="java.util.ArrayList">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <ref bean="impl1" />
            <ref bean="impl2" />
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

but because I set up an application.properties for each environment, I want to use this, to store a list of worker classes depending on which worker class is needed on the environment. But i don't find a way to bind the List of names to the List impls in class Scheduler.
Is there a Spring way to do this? My colleague mentioned it's not recommended in Spring to use a classical factory pattern on Beans..
I don't want to use Spring Profiles if it's possible without it.

Comment: you are saying you have an application.properties for each environment. And then you say you don't want to use Spring profiles. If you are not using spring profiles then how are you using different application.properties

Comment: we don't deploy our different application.properties with our normal deployments, they are just stored at the tomcats with the needed config. From the server side, there is only one application.property

Comment: check this out. This might give you an idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48681555/i-want-to-load-a-specific-class-based-on-a-flag-instead-of-loading-two-class-and/48681880#48681880

Comment: thanks to you, the hint with the Condition leads me to the @ConditionalOn* annotation. We decided to use the @ConditionalOnProperty in the implementations to check a flag in the application.properties